# Passing DropDownList value into SQL command in ASP.net

Tags: sql, asp.net, drop-down-menu, html-select, selectedvalue

I have a `DropDownList` which gets it values from SQL table 
I want to get the Average of the selected item (course in this case) from the `dropDownList` and to show it in a label :
This section works -

```
SqlConnection sqlConnection1;
    sqlConnection1 = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=HA\SQLEXPRESS; Initial Catalog=Grades1; Integrated Security=True");
    SqlCommand Command = null;
  
        Command = new SqlCommand("SELECT Course FROM GradesTable1", sqlConnection1);
        Command.Connection.Open();
        SqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(Command);
        DataTable dataTble1 = new DataTable();
        dataAdapter.Fill(dataTble1);

        if (dataTble1.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (DataRow row in dataTble1.Rows)
            {
                ListItem course1 = new ListItem(row["Course"].ToString());
                if (!DropDownList1.Items.Contains(course1))
                {
                    DropDownList1.Items.Add(course1); // showing the 2 courses
                }
            }
        }
        Command.Connection.Close();

    }
}
```

Here is the problem - (I get nothing, no data )

```
protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection sqlConnection1;
    sqlConnection1 = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=HA\SQLEXPRESS; Initial Catalog=Grades1; Integrated Security=True");
    SqlCommand Command = null;
  
        Command = new SqlCommand($"SELECT AVG(Grade) FROM GradesTable1 WHERE Course = @course", sqlConnection1);
        Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@course", DropDownList1.SelectedItem);
        Command.Connection.Open();
        SqlDataReader sqlDataReader1 = Command.ExecuteReader();

        if (sqlDataReader1.Read())
        {
            LabelAverage.Text = sqlDataReader1[0].ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            LabelAverage.Text = "No Data"; // doesn't get into here anyhow
        }
   }
```

**EDIT** 
I tried several variations as `$"SELECT AVG(Grade) AS "ClassAVG" FROM GradesTable1 WHERE Course = @course"` and `Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@course", DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text)`, 
or  `DropDownList1.SelectedValue`

 I believe the problem is with the `DropDownlist` values which being received from the SQL and are not hard coded.

 Is there a correct way to this? is it possible without knowing what are the "`Courses`" in advanced?

Thanks for the answers, feel free to give your opinion.

Comment: I think DropDownList1.SelectedItem will be an Object.  Use .ToString()...

Comment: `DropDownList1.SelectedValue`

Comment: Tried all of these before and nothing works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out what was missing in the `DropDownList` in `aspx` page (not the `aspx.cs` page) -the  **`AutoPostBack="true"`** 
Adding that to `DropDownList` solved the problem.

Answer (score -1):

// query = Sql query

```
query.Select(s => new MusteriNoktaComboItemDTO
            {
                Label = s.Adi,
                Value = s.ID.ToString()
            }).ToList();
```